# Nodejs Google cloud storage returns 403 when accessing public url

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading a profile image to google cloud store (which works fine) and trying to make all of the images publicly available, however I keep getting a 403 error from the returned url when used inside of img src or just pasting it in the browser, the returned url looks as follows:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/my_bucket_name/12370691_1205162746164520_2152367844899316112_o.jpg
```

and it gives the following error:

```
Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object my_bucket_name/15991995_384418798568801_734448169_o.jpg.
```

> note: my_bucket_name is not the real bucket name, it's just a placeholder for
>   this post

The code below shows how i set google cloud store up:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
  projectId: ‘my_project_id’,
  keyFilename: './routes/to/my/keyfile.json'
});

const bucket = gcs.bucket(‘my_bucket_name’);

const options = {
  entity: 'allUsers',
  role: gcs.acl.READER_ROLE
};

bucket.acl.add(options, (err, aclObject) => {
  console.log(err); //null
  console.log(aclObject); //{ entity: 'allUsers', role: 'READER' }
});

function getPublicUrl(filename) {
  return `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${filename}`;
}

... code for uploading the image below, (works fine)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `bucket.acl.add` with `bucket.acl.update` fixes the problem by making the bucket publicly readable, running this code once is enough to change the default bucket's ACL permissions, you can remove the code afterwards:

```
const options = {
  entity: 'allUsers',
  role: gcs.acl.READER_ROLE
};

bucket.acl.update(options, (err, aclObject) => {
  console.log(err); //null
  console.log(aclObject); //{ entity: 'allUsers', role: 'READER' }
});
```

Note: the same could be accomplished using:

```
gsutil defacl set public-read gs://[YOUR-BUCKET-NAME]
```

If you don't want to make the entire bucket readable, i.e. url/bucket_name, and only want to make files inside of the bucket readable then you need to configure the file to be readable by anonymous users at file write time as shown below:

```
  const remoteWriteStream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype
    },
    predefinedAcl: "publicRead"
  });
```